# Is there any way to link a field in a Scapy Packet to its portion in the built str?

Tags: python, scapy, coap

I'm using Scapy to manipulate CoAP packets. Now I found one thing I want to do which I actually can't figure out how.

I have the following CoAP Packet:

```
>>> pkt
<CoAP  ver=1L type=CON tkl=8L code=PUT msg_id=<RandShort> token=<RandBin> options=[('If-Match', '\x04\xfc\xbbL'), ('Content-Format', ''), ('Uri-Path', '.well-known'), ('Uri-Path', 'core')] paymark='\xff' |<Raw  load='CC22 at 12:39:31.495' |>>
>>> str(pkt)
'H\x03\xf4\x08\xbdR_\x85\xa3\x04\xe9\xe9\x14\x04\xfc\xbbL\xab.well-known\x04core\x10\xffCC22 at 12:39:31.495'
```

What I'd like to do now is to replace the whole part (not the Option Value `''`) representing the option at index 1 `('Content-Format', '')` to null (`\x00`) chars. I know this part is represented by `str(pkt)[-22:-21]` near the end of the `str(pkt)`, which has value `\x10` to represent the Content-Format option with no actual value on it.

So, I wonder: is there a way to obtain `\x10` (actually, to obtain the reference `str(pkt)[-22:-21]`) from the high-level field (`pkt.options[1]`), so I can replace this part of the string by another value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few hours on the problem and I came up with a solution which, if I'm correct to assume there's no easy way to do this through Scapy itself (probably due to the way CoAP Options are implemented in the CoAP contrib layer), seems to be a fair enough one.

The following function can be used to "nullify" an entire CoAP Option field:

```
def coap_option_to_null(pkt, opt_idx):
  ''' Changes the whole CoAP Option field at @opt_idx to null '''
  opt = pkt.options[opt_idx]
  l = pkt.options
  # Sort the list of options by option number
  l.sort( lambda x, y: cmp(coap_options[1][x[0]], coap_options[1][y[0]]) )
  # Replace options for the sorted one and grabs new opt_idx
  pkt.options = l
  opt_idx = pkt.options.index(opt)

  cur_delta = 0
  opt_total_len = []
  for opt in pkt.options:
    if (option_model[opt[0]][0] - cur_delta) < 13:
      delta_extended = 0
    elif (option_model[opt[0]][0] - cur_delta) < 269:
      delta_extended = 1
    else:
      delta_extended = 2
    cur_delta += (option_model[opt[0]][0] - cur_delta)

    if len(opt[1]) < 13:
      len_extended = 0
    elif len(opt[1]) < 269:
      len_extended = 1
    else:
      len_extended = 2

    opt_total_len.append(1+delta_extended+len_extended+len(opt[1]))

  opt_lidx = sum(opt_total_len[:opt_idx])
  opt_hidx = sum(opt_total_len[opt_idx+1:])
  new_pkt = str(pkt)[:4+pkt.tkl+opt_lidx] + '\x00'*opt_total_len[opt_idx] + str(pkt)[-(len(pkt.payload)+1+sum(opt_total_len[opt_idx+1:])):]
      return CoAP(new_pkt)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> pkt
<CoAP  ver=1L type=CON tkl=8L code=PUT msg_id=<RandShort> token=<RandBin> options=[('If-Match', '\x04\xfc\xbbL'), ('Content-Format', ''), ('Uri-Path', 'separate')] paymark='\xff' |<Raw  load='CC22 at 12:39:31.495' |>>
>>> str(pkt)
'H\x03*\x88%T\xbe\xac\xd9\xee\xcd\xbd\x14\x04\xfc\xbbL\xa8separate\x10\xffCC22 at 12:39:31.495'
>>> npkt = coap_option_to_null(pkt, 1)
>>> npkt
<CoAP  ver=1L type=CON tkl=8L code=PUT msg_id=47784 token='\x90L\x0f\xd4u\xbe&\xd7' options=[('If-Match', '\x04\xfc\xbbL'), ('Uri-Path', 'separate'), ('Uri-Path', '')] paymark='\xff' |<Raw  load='CC22 at 12:39:31.495' |>>
>>> str(npkt)
'H\x03\xba\xa8\x90L\x0f\xd4u\xbe&\xd7\x14\x04\xfc\xbbL\xa8separate\x00\xffCC22 at 12:39:31.495'



>>> pkt
<CoAP  ver=1L type=CON tkl=8L code=PUT msg_id=<RandShort> token=<RandBin> options=[('If-Match', '\x04\xfc\xbbL'), ('Content-Format', ''), ('Uri-Path', 'separate')] paymark='\xff' |<Raw  load='CC22 at 12:39:31.495' |>>
>>> npkt = coap_option_to_null(pkt, 0)
>>> npkt
<CoAP  ver=1L type=CON tkl=8L code=PUT msg_id=14606 token='s\xad\xd0\xf5\x05\xac\x87C' options=[(0L, ''), (0L, ''), (0L, ''), (0L, ''), (0L, ''), (10L, 'separate'), ('Uri-Path', '')] paymark='\xff' |<Raw  load='CC22 at 12:39:31.495' |>>
>>> str(npkt)
'H\x039\x0es\xad\xd0\xf5\x05\xac\x87C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa8separate\x10\xffCC22 at 12:39:31.495'
```